# How set comparison works in python?

Tags: python, set, comparison

**Code:**

```
 x = {3, 7}    
 y = {1, 3, 7, 14}     
 a = x <= y
```

The answer given to this question is a boolean `True`. Can somebody explain how they came to that conclusion?

Comment: `<=` is a conditional statement which is suppose to return boolean value. what other answer do you expect?

Comment: `x` is a **subset** of `y`, so `x <= y` returns `True` which is then assigned to `a`

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) explains this:

> `set <= other`
>
> Test whether every element in the set is in other.

So, since every element in x is also in y, the comparison is true.